# How to puts arguments in one line?

Tags: ruby

I want to make it like in Python, 4 example:

```
print(
    foobar,
    footree,
    foodrink
)
```

and it will be print in one line:

```
>>> "foobar, footree, foodrink"
```

In Ruby with the same code:

```
puts foobar,
     footree,
     foodrink

>>> "foobar"
... "footree"
... "foodrink"
```

Yes, I can do it with print, like this, but it looks ugly:

```
puts  "foobar" +
      "foobar" +
      "foobar" +

>>> "foobar, footree, foodrink"
```

Thx in advance!

[image]

**Edited.** Now I have the following "Align the arguments of a method call if they span more than one line" and in terminal it output from a new line, I need it in one line.

Comment: You might want to double check the outputs you are claiming.  Why would there be quotes, commas and `>>>` printed by your first block of code?  Why would there be commas, spaces, and `>>>` printed in the last block of code?  What is the exact output you are looking for when you judge answers people submit to your question?

Comment: I can do it like this: 


```puts event['BK1_name'], event['BK1_bet'], event['BK1_game'], event['BK1_cf']```

but, is it right way?

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more clear what data types you're working with.  Your examples show a mixture of both named variables and plain old strings.  In addition, your examples are not reproducible in that you're demonstrating something that will not actually work as you have shown--at least not without more information as to what data types you're working with and how any variables are being defined.

Comment: `puts`  [by definition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/IO.html#method-i-puts) applies `to_s` to each argument and adds a newline to those arguments which don't have one. So for your application, this function is useful only if you supply a single argument (for instance. `puts([foo,bar,baz].join)`) or use a different function (for instance `print`, which means that you have to provide the newline explicitly). Of course if you need this frequently in your program, you could consider monkey-patching the `IO` class by providing a completely new method which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> a, b = "bar", "tree"
>> puts [a, b].join(", ")
bar, tree
```

or `print`:

```
>> print a, ", ", b, "\n"
bar, tree
```

Comment: And what is the max length it could be?

`>> print a, ", ", b, "\n", c, d, v`

Thanks my friend!

Comment: @SonyMag i'm not sure, but a lot. `100_000`  works `print *100_000.times.map{rand(10)}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to do

```
puts "#{foobar}, #{footree}, \
#{foodrink}"
```

Comment: Thx friend! But its not, what I am looking 4

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about your various data types based on limited information given in your example, but the closest syntax I can come up with is using an `array`(`[]`) along with `p` and `join` like so:

```
foobar = "foobar"
footree = "footree"
foodrink = "foodrink"

p [
    foobar,
    footree,
    foodrink
].join(" ")
#=>  "foobar footree foodrink"
```